# How to use COALESCE in go with the database/sql lib?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to pass arguments into a postgres sql statement that are injection safe.

I’m having a bit of trouble with passing in arugements using DB.Query of the database/sql package in Go.

This is what Postgres registers

```
STATEMENT:  SELECT mc.company_name_full, msc.company_id, msc.cdate, msc.value->>'n_rules', msc.value->>'pct_interfaces_classified'
                  FROM mn_company AS mc INNER JOIN mn_statistics_company AS msc
                      ON (mc.id = msc.company_id)
                  WHERE (msc.value->>'n_rules')::int>0 AND (msc.value->>'pct_interfaces_classified')::int>0  AND
                      msc.company_id = COALESCE('$1', msc.company_id) AND
                      mc.company_name_full ~* COALESCE('$2', mc.company_name_full) AND
                      msc.cdate >= COALESCE('$3', 2017-07-01) AND
                  msc.cdate <= COALESCE('$4', 2017-09-19)
```

This is my function call

```
rows, err := a.DB.Query(*query, qf.companyIDFilter, qf.companyNameFilter, firstDate, secondDate)
```

all arguments that are being pasted into a.DB.Query are pointers.

I’m trying to replaces the $1, $2,… with arguments

Comment: Have you tried to dereference them? `rows, err := a.DB.Query(*query, *qf.companyIDFilter, *qf.companyNameFilter, ...)` ?

Comment: Their default values are null though...  Could the sql query know that it is null if I pass NULL as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...):

```
query := `SELECT mc.company_name_full, msc.company_id, msc.cdate, msc.value->>'n_rules', msc.value->>'pct_interfaces_classified'
                  FROM mn_company AS mc INNER JOIN mn_statistics_company AS msc
                      ON (mc.id = msc.company_id)
                  WHERE (msc.value->>'n_rules')::int>0 AND (msc.value->>'pct_interfaces_classified')::int>0  AND
                      msc.company_id = COALESCE($1, msc.company_id) AND
                      mc.company_name_full ~* COALESCE($2, mc.company_name_full) AND
                      msc.cdate >= COALESCE($3, 2017-07-01) AND
                  msc.cdate <= COALESCE($4, 2017-09-19)`
```

The lib/pq package automatically adds the quotes where needed.